# Lua is not working in Openresty on Mac OS X

Tags: nginx, lua

I am trying to install Openresty v.1.2.6.7 under Mac OS X 10.6.
I am installing pcre with brew in order to satisfy the requirements 
(pcre is version 8.32) and run the configure script with the pcre directories
specified and the --with-luajit option.

```
cd openresty-1.2.6.7

./configure --with-cc-opt="-I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.32/include" \
            --with--ld-opt="-L/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.32/lib" |
            --with-luajit
```

I am using the example conf given in the Openresty guide:

http://openresty.org/#GettingStarted

and try to start nginx with it but I am getting the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "content_by_lua"
```

I tried the same steps in Ubuntu (with the necessary changes in prerequisite packages and worked fine). Any suggestion is highly welcome.

Comment: This probably wouldn't help you very much, but just yesterday I published a [brew tap for openresty](https://github.com/killercup/homebrew-openresty). It keeps stuff in brew and makes future updates easy. Further more, the binary will be called `openresty`, not `nginx`.

Comment: Sounds interesting and I guess it will overcome the problem as well. I will give it a try :) Thank you for your consideration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple of days I found it. I installed seperately LuaJIT with brew and used its libraries and header in building openresty.

```
cd openresty-1.2.6.7

./configure --with-cc-opt="-I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.32/include 
                           -I/usr/local/Cellar/luajit/2.01/luajit2.0/include" \
            --with--ld-opt="-L/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.32/lib
                            -L/usr/local/Cellar/luajit/2.01/luajit2.0/lib" \                
            --with-luajit
```

Build it with

```
 make && make install
```

and it worked

Answer (score 3):

Why not to just use Brew?

```
brew install openresty
```

and thats all! :)

Comment: You might need to `brew tap killercup/homebrew-openresty` first, see: https://github.com/killercup/homebrew-openresty

Comment: `brew install homebrew/nginx/openresty` seems to work nowadays.